# Regex for gsub in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, kaminari

I have a rails application where I am using kaminari for pagination.

Somehow kaminari is using wrong url for hyperlinks.

Right now I am looking for an easy fix which requires some regex & gsubbing.

I have this url from kaminari:

```
"/bookings/hotels//Pune?arrival_date=....."
```

I want  to replace this part - `/hotels//Pune?` with this - `/hotels?`

There could be any other string in place of `Pune` (it might change).

How should I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture and replace using [`match capture`](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/gsub#1094-Working-with-match-captures)

```
gsub(/hotels(\/\/\w+)\?/){|m| m.gsub($1, '')}

str = "/bookings/hotels//Pune?arrival_date=....."
str.gsub(/hotels(\/\/\w+)\?/){|m| m.gsub($1, '')}

#=> "/bookings/hotels?arrival_date=....."
```

Answer (score 1):

I always use the [URI library](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) when messing around with URLs, it does some of the legwork for you (especially if query strings are involved).

Something like this would suit your situation, although there's probably a way to get the right URL in the first place too!

```
require 'uri' # probably not necessary if you are using Rails

old_url  = "/bookings/hotels//Pune?arrival_date=blahblah"
uri      = URI(old_url)

# remove everything between the first double '//' and the end of the string
uri.path = uri.path.gsub(/\/\/.+\Z/, '')
# => "/bookings/hotels"

# output a new url using the new path but including the original query string
new_url  = uri.to_s
# =>  "/bookings/hotels?arrival_date=blahblah"
```

Answer (score 0):

gsub("//Pune", "")
No needs 4 regexp here.

Comment: Well I have to say sorry as I didn't mention that Pune part would be dynamic.
I will edit the question.